# Table keeps float value

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm working on a program that generates table scripts to insert data into forms.

Yesterday I had a problem, because a table came with values ​​in decimal("4,2"). The value in this case has to be 4,200.

Anyway, I managed to solve this with a simple calculation and replacing the value in the table, but the value in the table is 4200.0.

```
for i in range(table.shape[0]):
     if pd.isna(table[1][i]) == True:
         table = table.drop(labels=i, axis=0) 

# Criar nova tabela
table2 = pd.DataFrame(table)
# Resetar o index da nova tabela
table2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

for i in range(5):
     valor1 = table2[1][i]
     valor2 = int(table2[1][i] * 1000)
     table2[1] = table2[1].replace([valor1], int(valor2))
```

Comment: Can you create a [reprex]?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your problem since 4200.0 = 4,200 = 4*1000 + 200 (using '.' as decimal separator (standard in English)).

If you want to use ',' as decimal separator (like in Portuguese and most European languages.), then you can do it by working on the initial text string "4,2". Start by replacing any '.' with an empty string using .replace('.','') and then replace any ',' by a '.' using .replace(',','.').

```
a = "4,2"
a = a.replace('.','').replace(',','.')
print(a)
>>>4.2
```

Comment: Imho it seems to be an issue of number formatting. The number is there but Bjorn would better format it as `int` and not as `float`.